# UITableView, could not set textlabel.text and text.label.font

Tags: ios, uitableview

In viewDidLoad I add

```
[super viewDidLoad];
if ([[API sharedInstance] isAuthorized]) {
    [self userInfo];
}
```

then

```
-(void)userInfo{
API* apiUser = [API sharedInstance];
//load the caption of the selected photo

[apiUser commandWithParams: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"get_user_data", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //got stream
    NSArray* list = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [list objectAtIndex:0];
    name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"name"], [userInfo objectForKey:@"surname"]];
}];
}
```

finally cell.textLabel.text and cell.textLabel.font got nothing, text is the same as in storyboard and font is default

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    if (name != nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = name;
    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.0 blue:0.03 alpha:1.0];
     UIFont *myfontTop = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:IS_PAD?17:11];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = myfontTop;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

} else {
    UIFont *myfont = [ UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:IS_PAD?17:11];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = myfont;
}

return cell;
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the problem?

Comment: `[self.tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: where I need to reload data?

Comment: After you have obtained new data that should be shown on the table view

Comment: Thx I found where I could place reload, but now it's not in storyboard style at all, I need to change it by code? not with storyboard?